# Is it possible to attack the same village twice?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have been playing clash of clans for a while now and I have recently upgraded to a level 8 town hall. Out of all of my battles I cannot remember if I have battled the same village twice or not. I understand that the layouts can be the same piece by piece but what I mean is the name of the village. I am curious of this because I am hoping that I would be able to fight one of the really easy idle villages that I have attacked before for about 400k loot again. Please note that I have put into consideration shield time with these layouts.

Comment: Yes it is. Why are you having trouble with it?

Comment: No I just like the easy loot. Can you show any proof or explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is extremely unlikely that you will ever come across the same village twice.

Quote from "[Raids](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids)" page on the wiki:

> Matchmaking matches you with another player based on your Trophies.

This means when you first attacked this player, you both would have had the correct amount of trophies for the matchmaking algorithm, and therefore you were given his base to attack!

The chances of both you and the other player to have the correct amount of trophies, as well as being randomly picked from millions of players, are minuscule.

Comment: I thank you for the answer but there is one little flaw, you can't revenge a revenge attack. Trust me I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to find and attack the same village again and again, as the matchup is (almost) completely random. I say almost because there are a couple of factors involved:

1. Your level. This is a placeholder for who you can attack, for example of you are lvl 5, you won't be set up with a level 20.
2. Availability. If you have just recently attacked a town, you can't attack them again until their shield either runs out, or until they take it down by attacking other players.

However, if you're patient enough, you can find the same village. Personally I have been attacked by the top 10 multiple times in a week, and up to 5 times by the same player.

Comment: I don't believe that the level of your village makes a difference in the match making. Doesn't it say that in the tutorial and the wiki? Also, as a level 5 and level 1 town hall I have encountered people with level 10 town halls and, for example purposes, level 70 village

Comment: I believe you are mixed up between level and trophies?

Comment: Possibly hahaha

Comment: Levels don't do anything but give you a rough guide in how much work a person has done and inflate their ego. trophies do matter as players trying to avoid attacks will send a single unit to attack and surrender to loose on purpose and lower their trophy count so this will face newer places who are least likely to steal their resources

Answer (score -1):

You can attack the same person as many times as you like, without paying gold, very simply. However, this only works if they attack you or the want ŗevenge. You can use your ŗevenge button as many times as you want. I have attacked person that has max producers, storages, and town hall 7 about 12 times now.

Comment: This is incorrect, whenever i have used the Revenge button it disappears after the attack (it's how i keep track on who i have dumped trophies to). also if you attack and they revenge you, there is no revenge button from their attack (having been revenged after dumping trophies)